# Java : string manipulation in numbers to six digit

Tags: java, string, format, character

Case 1 if number is 123 result : 000123
Case 2 if number is 00123123 result : 123123
case 3 if number is 10231239 result : 10231239
case 4 if number is 01231239 result : 1231239

What i have tried is bellow but need better solution for this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String number = "0023213";
    number = number.trim();
    String result;
    if(number.length() < 6)
    {
        result = String.format("%06d", Integer.parseInt(number));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    else if (number.trim().length()>6)
    {
        result = number.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
        result = String.format("%06d", Integer.parseInt(result));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: So all you want to do is remove 0s at the beginning?

Comment: its not just remove 0's in the beginning but keep it six digits too by appending leading  0's , also if number is like 1231235 its  has to be same  and if number is like 01123123  result has to be 1123123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Apache Common Lang library:

```
String str = "1123456";
str = StringUtils.leftPad(StringUtils.stripStart(str, "0"), 6, "0");
```

I think this is more readable at all.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work for you (code for the else part). Removes leading zeros as long as there are 6 digits after it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "0023123";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^0+(?=\\d{6})", ""));
}
```

O/P

```
023123
```

Sample input : 00000110023123

Sample Output : 110023123